# Javascript objects value from concatenated string keys in nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, typescript

I'm trying to get the value of a nested object but my input is a string. Maybe it could be done with a for loop or recursive function, but that seems excessive complexity.

my object would be something like

```
a : {
  b : {
    c : 1
  }
}
```

and the input is the string `"b.c"`

how can I get the value of `c` from this?

Comment: Shouldn't the input string be `a.b.c` ?

Comment: no that's the thing, my input is "b.c" @0stone0